# Creating .log files with logging's TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

I would expect the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` to create .log files, but instead it creates files without extension. Is there any way I can set up the handler to generate log files?

What I want in a nutshell:  `file_name.2019-10-09.log`, instead of `file_name.log.2019-10-09`.

Comment: ...have you tried passing a `filename` with `.log` extension?

Comment: The problem is, logging adds a date suffix to the file, changing its extension, e.g.: filename.log.2019-10-09.

Answer (score 1):

From the class' documentation (emphasis mine):

> The system will save old log files by **appending extensions to the filename**. The extensions are date-and-time based, using the strftime format %Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S or a leading portion thereof, depending on the rollover interval.

This, plus the implementation of the [`doRollover` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/01171ebd966b0cd6352057799ad876dd1e07942e/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L398) show that the class will simply append the time to whatever filename the old log file has. There seems to be no way for you to force it to keep the same file extension.

Comment: You can force it to keep the extension by creating a subclass and recreating the self.namer function.

Answer (score 0):

Here my code example, can ignore extra arguments. I have in a Singleton class

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


rhandler = RotatingFileHandler("your_desired_FILENAME_logger.out" ,
                                       mode="a+",
                                       maxBytes=10*1024*1024,
                                       backupCount=5)
```